# python sql interval

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pygresql

With PostgreSQL, one of my tables has an 'interval' column, values of which I would like to extract as something I can manipulate (datetime.timedelta?); however I am using PyGreSQL which seems to be returning intervals as strings, which is less than helpful.

Where should I be looking to either parse the interval or make PyGreSQL return it as a <something useful>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Psycopg 2.  It correctly converts between Postgres's interval data type and Python's timedelta.

Comment: Not really psycopg2 returns a timedelta of -1 day, 23 hour when you have a value of -1 hour interval in your postgresql table